# Спонтанная перезагрузка приложения при hot-fix

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

Добрый день.

Имею веб-приложение следующего состава: Maven, Spring Framework, Spring MVC, Spring Security, JSP, Hibernate, работает на сервере Pivotal tc Server (входит в состав Spring Tool Suite, тот же Tomcat).

Как известно, если при запущенном приложении редактировать исходники и сохранить их, приложение будет перезагружаться. Страницы же JSP компилируются "на лету", и поэтому при их редактировании приложение не перезагружается.

Итак, при запущенном приложении я редактирую JSP и сохраняю несколько раз. Все нормально, но через некоторое время (час-два или же пять минут) приложение спонтанно перезапускается, и выдает

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'customUserDetailsService' is defined
```

Разумеется, до этого этот бин был на месте. Этот бин нужен для Spring Security, как видно из имени. Подозреваю, именно его Spring загружает в первую очередь, и если его бы не было, он споткнулся бы на следующем.

Перезагружаю сервер, все хорошо. Иногда это не помогает, приходится делать Maven Update Project. Иногда и это не помогает, приходится удалять приложение с сервера и добавлять его туда заново.

Более того, пару раз приложение просто так не хотело запускаться с этой же ошибкой.

Что это? Проблема конфигурации? Конфликт контекстов?

Comment: Вообще, у Tomcat [большое кол-во настроек](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jasper-howto.html). Может ваш сервер как-то по другому преднастроен. Посмотрите дебаг самого Tomcat (не Spring), может там что-то дельное есть?

Comment: спасибо, мб поможет